# why ggplotly of a ggplot2 object throw the error "Error in : Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" althoug the y axis is numerical?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, ggplotly

i am building an R shiny app that is supposed to plot some graphs.I have to apply some outliers removal method and the plot two variables against each others. It is about 3 plots besides each others : My problem is that when i run my App locally but on R server linux i got nices plors but after docker deployment the App threw the "Error in : Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" when i check its structure files i find it is not empty and numerical. I struggling since one month with problem. Could Anybody help?. I forget to tell you that i am using plotly::ggplotly and renderplotly in order to a plotly plot.In Log lines it is always mentioned that error lines is exactly the one containing "plotly::ggplotly".

```
observe({
    tryCatch({
    req(cleanMethod())
    
    req(input$Parmeter)
    req(Par_plot_data())
    #requiring all the available methods and their coefficients
    lapply(input$Parmeter, function(par){
      if (cleanMethod()=="None"){
      #plotting the scatter plot of the parameter plus all the options(colours,size...)
      if (!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
        scatterplot<-ggplot(PlotData(), aes(x =Lot,y = PlotData()[[par]])) +
          labs(y=par)+
          geom_point(size=2,colour="#007A9D",shape=4)+
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
          theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(colour = "#007A9D"),
                axis.title.y.left  = element_text(colour = "#007A9D"))
      }
      #case where the parameter is numeric or integer but completely not available
      else if ((is.null(PlotData()[[par]]))) {
        scatterplot<-NULL
      }
      # This is the histogram plot .Plotted only when the parameter numeric is.
      if (((is.numeric(PlotData()[[par]]))|| (is.integer(PlotData()[[par]])))&!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
        histogramme<- ggplot(PlotData(), aes(y = PlotData()[[par]])) +
          geom_histogram() +
          labs(y = NULL)}
      else{
        histogramme<-NULL
      }
      
      # This is the text box. Always plotted but the values can be real numbers or NAs based oh the type of the paramter (numerical or character)
      text_box<-  ggplot(PlotData()) +
        theme_void() +
        annotate(
          geom = "text",
          x = 0, y = .5,
          label = 
            if (((is.numeric(PlotData()[[par]]))|| (is.integer(PlotData()[[par]])))&!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
              paste(
                "Mean = ", round(mean(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1), "\n",
                "Sigma = ", round(sd(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
                "Min = ", round(min(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
                "Max = ", round(max(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1)
                
              )}
          
          #case where the parameter is character or logical
          else if(((is.character(PlotData()[[par]])) ||(is.logical(PlotData()[[par]])))&!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
            paste(
              "Mean = ",NA, "\n",
              "Sigma = ",NA,"\n",
              "Min = ", NA,"\n",
              "Max = ", NA
            )}
          #case where the parameter is character or logical
          else if(is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
            paste(
              "Mean = ",NA, "\n",
              "Sigma = ",NA,"\n",
              "Min = ", NA,"\n",
              "Max = ", NA
            )}
          
          
          ,
          hjust = 0
        )
      }
      
     else if (cleanMethod()=="Alpha*Sigma"){
       if (!(par %in% colnames(LimitData()))){
        #plotting the scatter plot of the parameter plus all the options(colours,size...)
        if (!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
          scatterplot<-ggplot(PlotData(), aes(x =Lot,y = PlotData()[[par]])) +
            labs(y=par)+
            geom_point(size=2,colour="#007A9D",shape=4)+
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
            theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                  axis.title.y.left  = element_text(color = "#007A9D"))
        }
        #case where the parameter is numeric or integer but completely not available
        else if ((is.null(PlotData()[[par]]))) {
          scatterplot<-NULL
        }
        # This is the histogram plot .Plotted only when the parameter numeric is.
        if (((is.numeric(PlotData()[[par]]))|| (is.integer(PlotData()[[par]])))&!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
          histogramme<- ggplot(PlotData(), aes(y = PlotData()[[par]])) +
            geom_histogram() +
            labs(y = NULL)}
        else{
          histogramme<-NULL
        }
        
        # This is the text box. Always plotted but the values can be real numbers or NAs based oh the type of the paramter (numerical or character)
        text_box<-  ggplot(PlotData()) +
          theme_void() +
          annotate(
            geom = "text",
            x = 0, y = .5,
            label = 
              if (((is.numeric(PlotData()[[par]]))|| (is.integer(PlotData()[[par]])))&!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
                paste(
                  "Mean = ", round(mean(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1), "\n",
                  "Sigma = ", round(sd(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
                  "Min = ", round(min(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
                  "Max = ", round(max(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1)
                  
                )}
            
            #case where the parameter is character or logical
            else if(((is.character(PlotData()[[par]])) ||(is.logical(PlotData()[[par]])))&!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
              paste(
                "Mean = ",NA, "\n",
                "Sigma = ",NA,"\n",
                "Min = ", NA,"\n",
                "Max = ", NA
              )}
            #case where the parameter is character or logical
            else if(is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
              paste(
                "Mean = ",NA, "\n",
                "Sigma = ",NA,"\n",
                "Min = ", NA,"\n",
                "Max = ", NA
              )}
            ,
            hjust = 0
          )}
    
        
       else if (par %in% colnames(LimitData())){
         #plotting the scatter plot of the parameter plus all the options(colours,size...)
      
         if (!is.null(PlotData()[[par]]) && is.numeric(PlotData()[[par]])){
           XLog(print(PlotData()[[par]]))
           XLog(is.character(PlotData()[[par]]))
           upperLimit<-reactive({LimitData()[,par][1]})
           lowerLimit<-reactive({LimitData()[,par][2]})
           mean_wt = data.frame(wt=c(upperLimit(),lowerLimit()))
           scatterplot<-ggplot(PlotData(), aes(x =Lot,y = PlotData()[[par]])) +
             geom_point(size=2,color="#007A9D",shape=4)+
             labs(y=par)+
             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
            theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                  axis.title.y.left  = element_text(color = "#007A9D"))+
             geom_hline(mean_wt,  mapping=aes(yintercept = wt), color = "#007A9D")
         
           
           
         }
         else if ((!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])  && is.character(PlotData()[[par]]))||
         (!is.null(PlotData()[[par]]) && !all(is.na(PlotData()[[par]])) && is.logical(PlotData()[[par]]))){
           scatterplot<-ggplot(PlotData(), aes(x =Lot,y = PlotData()[[par]])) +
             geom_point(size=2,colour="#007A9D",shape=4)+
             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
             theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(colour = "#007A9D"),
                   axis.title.y.left  = element_text(colour = "#007A9D"))
             
           
         }
         #case where the parameter is numeric or integer but completely not available
         else if (is.null(PlotData()[[par]]) || all(is.na(PlotData()[[par]]))) {
           scatterplot<-NULL
         }
         # This is the histogram plot .Plotted only when the parameter numeric is.
         if (((is.numeric(PlotData()[[par]]))|| (is.integer(PlotData()[[par]])))&!is.null(Par_plot_data()[[par]])){
           histogramme<- ggplot(PlotData(), aes(y =PlotData()[[par]])) +
             geom_histogram() +
             labs(y = NULL)}
         else{
           histogramme<-NULL
         }
         
         # This is the text box. Always plotted but the values can be real numbers or NAs based oh the type of the paramter (numerical or character)
         text_box<-  ggplot(PlotData()) +
           theme_void() +
           annotate(
             geom = "text",
             x = 0, y = .5,
             label = 
               if (((is.numeric(PlotData()[[par]]))|| (is.integer(PlotData()[[par]])))&!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
                 paste(
                   "Mean = ", round(mean(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1), "\n",
                   "Sigma = ", round(sd(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
                   "Min = ", round(min(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1),"\n",
                   "Max = ", round(max(PlotData()[[par]],na.rm=T), 1)
                   
                 )}
             
             #case where the parameter is character or logical
             else if(((is.character(PlotData()[[par]])) ||(is.logical(PlotData()[[par]])))&!is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
               paste(
                 "Mean = ",NA, "\n",
                 "Sigma = ",NA,"\n",
                 "Min = ", NA,"\n",
                 "Max = ", NA
               )}
             #case where the parameter is character or logical
             else if(is.null(PlotData()[[par]])){
               paste(
                 "Mean = ",NA, "\n",
                 "Sigma = ",NA,"\n",
                 "Min = ", NA,"\n",
                 "Max = ", NA
               )}
             
             
             ,
             hjust = 0
           )  
       }
      }
      #Rendering the three plots together to plotly styled one plot.
      output[[paste("plot", par, sep = "_")]] <- renderPlotly({
        figure3<-plotly::ggplotly(scatterplot)
        figure1<-plotly::ggplotly(histogramme)
        figure2<-plotly::ggplotly(text_box)
        if (((is.numeric(PlotData()[[par]])) || (is.integer(PlotData()[[par]]))) && !is.null(PlotData()[[par]]) ){
        subplot(figure2,figure3,figure1,widths = c(0.1,0.7,0.2),titleY = T)

        }
        else if(is.null(PlotData()[[par]]) ) {
          subplot(figure2,widths = c(0.1),titleY = T)
        }
        else if(((is.character(PlotData()[[par]])) ||(is.logical(PlotData()[[par]]))) && !is.null(PlotData()[[par]]) ){
          subplot(figure2,figure3,widths = c(0.1,0.7),titleY = T)}
      })
      
    })
    }, error = function(e){
      error_txt <- paste0("in Alpha*sigma Method ",e)
      XLog(error_txt, type="Error")
    })
    
   
    })
```

The plots work well when not applying the alpha*sigma method (locally before deployment and after deployment in the server)
Applying the Alpha*sigma method works well  locally in server . But after applying it to the data set with some other basic functions like as.integer and as.double.factor (built by me) all the variables that are converted to characters but reconverted to numericals become NAs (of course i mean after deployed with docker in the linux server).Below the function +application of it+ transformation+ as.double.function:

```
 AlphaSigma<-function(a){
   coef_Alpha<-as.numeric(input$Alpha)
   
   if (is.character(a) || is.logical(a)|| is.factor(a)){a<-a}
   else if (is.numeric(a) || is.integer(a)){
     mittelwert<-mean(a,na.rm=T)
     st<-sd(a,na.rm=T)
     upperLimit<-mittelwert+(coef_Alpha*st)
     lowerLimit<-mittelwert-(coef_Alpha*st)
     a<-a[a>lowerLimit & a<upperLimit]
    
   }
   return(a)
 } 

 
 

PlotData <- reactive({
   req(cleanMethod()) 
   req(showData ())
   df <- showData ()
   #No method is selected
   if (cleanMethod()=="None"){df<-df}
   
   else if (cleanMethod()=="Alpha*Sigma"){
     #Applying the Alpha sigma method on the PlotData.This causes a difference in the lengths of various columns.
     newdf<-sapply(df,AlphaSigma)
     #building a new data frame where the shorter columns will be extended by NAs
     mydx<-do.call(rbind, data.table::transpose(newdf))
     #transforming to data frame
     mydx2<-as.data.frame(mydx)
     #assigning the right column names
     colnames(mydx2)<- names(newdf)
     #assigning the original type of variables to every column
     mydx2[1:2]<-sapply(mydx2[1:2],as.character)
     mydx2[3:4]<-sapply(mydx2[3:4],as.integer)
     mydx2[5:11]<-sapply(mydx2[5:11],as.logical)
     mydx2[12:20]<-sapply(mydx2[12:20],as.character)
     mydx2[21]<-sapply(mydx2[21],as.integer)
     mydx2[22:dim(mydx2)[2]]<-sapply(mydx2[22:dim(mydx2)[2]],as.double.factor)
     mydx2[22:dim(mydx2)[2]]<-as.data.frame(mydx2[22:dim(mydx2)[2]])
     #the last step is to assign the treated data frame to df
     df<-mydx2
     
   }
   return(df)
 })
```

Comment: Hi Samir. You have posted over 250 lines of code, most of which are not relevant to the specific error you are getting. Please post a minimal reproducible example. You are much less likely to attract a useful answer if you expect people to read through that amount of code

Comment: And as always ... sample data would be key to allowing us to even _try_ any portion of your code, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.